# Why is the derivative of $\arctan$ equal to the bottom side length of the triangle?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Consider a right triangle in the unit circle:

[image]

We know that $\frac{d}{da}\arctan(a)=\frac{1}{1 + a^2}$. And we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
r^2 + (ra)^2 &= 1\\
r^2(1 + a^2) &= 1\\
r^2 &= \frac{1}{1 + a^2}\\
\frac{d}{da}\arctan(a) &= r^2\\
\end{aligned}
$$

I found this very surprising. Why should the rate of change of $\theta$ as you change the ratio $a$ be equal to the length of the bottom leg, squared? I would love an intuitive explanation (handwavy is fine) of why these two things should be related. Or, if not that, a derivation of the result by some other means or another way of looking at it.

Comment: I don't see any $\theta$ in any of your equations.

Comment: Sorry -- it's the standard use, meaning the angle the hypotenuse makes with the x axis.

Answer (score 1):

You're taking a straight triangle, with legs $\;r\,,\,\,ra\;$ and hypotenuse $\;1\;$ , from which you get at once $\;r(1+a^2)=1\;$. Observe that if we put $\;\theta=\text{angle between hyopotenuse and horizontal leg}\;$, then we have

$$\tan\theta=\frac{ra}r=a\implies \theta=\arctan a$$

By the inverse function's derivative theorem, we get thus that

$$(\arctan a)'=\left.\frac1{(\tan \theta)'}\right|_{a\leftrightarrow\theta}=\left.\cos^2\theta\right|_{a\leftrightarrow\theta}=\left.\frac1{1+\tan^2\theta}\right|_{a\leftrightarrow\theta}=\frac1{1+a^2}$$

Comment: Thanks for bringing the inverse function theorem in, the connections are interesting. I'm not sure how you get from the third step (cos^2) to the fourth (1/(1 + tan^2)).

Comment: @EliRose It is a simple trigonometric identity: $$1+\tan^2x=1+\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}=\frac{\cos^2x+\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}=\frac1{ \cos^2x}$$

Comment: Oh, right. This is cool, but it seems like it uses only the inverse function theorem and not the $r(1 + a^2) = 1$ derivation. What I'm looking for is more an interpretation -- why should it be the case, intuitively, that $arctan(a)$'s rate of change is the bottom leg squared?